# Calculating the integral $ \int \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2+1} dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to calculate the integral $$ \int \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2+1} dx$$ strictly by using elementary functions.

Let $\displaystyle I(x)=\int \arctan^2(x) \ dx$. And now with the help of $I(x)$ we need to calculate the above integral.

I tried integration by parts but every direction I take seems to take to an even more complicated integral.

Comment: Any particular reason why you chose that $I(x)$? Also is it necessary to use that integral to solve the given integral?

Comment: $I(x)$ is a given in the question, I think we need it because all the solutions that I saw make use of the complex plane, while in here it all needs to be done on the real plane

Comment: @YousefS Can you please check my solution, I don't think you need to follow as complicated a procedure as you've mentioned.

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal I am trying it right now :) Will update in a few minutes

Comment: [The result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%281%2Bx%5E2%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29dx&dataset=) depends on the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). Are you familiar with it?

Comment: @J.G. I think that's why $I(x)$ is provided, to limit the problem to elementary functions.

Comment: If you integrate by parts twice, as described by one of the answers below, you'd do fine.

Comment: Substitute $x=\tan(u)$ so that $dx=\sec^2(u)\,du$. The integral becomes $2\int \ln(\sec u)\,du$ by which a closed form is calculated [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-solve-integral-ln-sec-x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to notice that $\int \frac{1}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx$ is $\arctan(x)$. Hence use by parts formula on $\int \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2+1}\mathrm dx$ to get $\ln(1 + x^{2})*\arctan(x) -\int \frac{\arctan(x)*2x}{1 + x^{2}}\mathrm dx$. Now, apply by parts again to this integral, by taking $\frac{2*\arctan(x)}{x^2+1}$ as the integrand, to obtain the final form in terms of $I(x)$. The final answer should look along the lines of $\ln(1 + x^{2})*\arctan(x) - x*{\arctan^{2}(x)} + I(x)$.

Comment: Solved! Thank you